# Apache Camel mockEndpoints() mocks all endpoints, instead of endpoints in advised route only

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to advice and mock endpoints of one particular route as follows:

```
RouteDefinition route = context.getRouteDefinition("process-search");
        route.adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                mockEndpoints();
            }
        });
```

Here, I expect that `mockEndpoints` will mock only endpoints within advised `process-search` route, but I see that endpoints within Camel Context are being adviced, as if I am using `context.getRouteDefinitions()` and then advice each of the route individually.

From `mockEndpoints()` `JavaDocs` -

> Mock all endpoints in the route.

I assume that endpoints are not associated with particular endpoint, they are reused. But in that case how can I limit advising to endpoints of the particular route only, without explicitly referencing them manually.

Version of Camel is 2.17.0.redhat-630310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc is a bit mistaken, it is really mocking all endpoints for all routes. You can only auto-mock by using filters, wildcards etc. We will update the javadoc for future Camel versions.

What is the specific reason you want to limit to endpoints in the route only. An endpoint can be shared among other routes etc, such as when you link routes together etc. Also mocking other endpoints for testing will not *affect* these endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have no functional reason  for limiting to particular route particularly, other than perceived overhead probably and understanding Camel behavior.

Comment: ok thanks, its a bit harder to automatic only mock endpoints from a given route, as endpoints can be created in many ways from a route, for example via an inlined processor sending to some endpoint, or via dynamic computed endpoints used by EIPs such as recipient list, dynamic router etc. So unless there are some good use-cases for limiting to a specific route that Camel users can justify, then lets leave it as it is today. I have polished the javadoc for Camel 3

Comment: You might want also to include this in CIA 2 errata, page 384.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the errata: https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/errata.txt